# getText() is not returning the link text in google

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to search in google for Mobile then trying to print the link on its heading. getText() is not returning any output.

```
package JavaExamples;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestLink {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("Mobile");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
        List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
        System.out.println(links.size());       
        for(int i=0; i<links.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(links.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the output. I suspect when we are sending the keys the results will start displaying, removing the button to click.

Comment: did you try `System.out.println(links[i].getText());`?

Comment: Did you debug your for loop and checked how many and which elements you were iterating over? You can also use debugging to check which values of the elements are set and what their getters return.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see anything wrong in your code

try to put

```
 try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

right after your

```
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
```

It should work fine ;)

Hope help.